# Mercurial Web Server - Why am I downloading a .bz2.tar file instead of a .tar.bz2 file?

Tags: mercurial, tar, bitbucket, bzip2

It is my understanding that a .tar file contains directories and other files, and a .bz2 is a file that's compressed with bzip2 compression.

Therefore, most tarballs with bzip2 compression end in:

```
.tar.bz2
```

Which is bzip2 compression applied to a tarball.

However, whenever I download source code from a Mercurial webserver, either the internal one that you get from:

```
hg serve
```

Or from BitBucket, I get something that ends in

```
.bz2.tar
```

Which doesn't make sense to me, because you can't apply bzip2 compression on multiple files, which is why you need to "tar" them up first.

Is this a bug in Mercurial?  Or is this a bug in my web browser (I've tried Google Chrome in Windows and Firefox in Ubuntu)?  Or is this something that's just weird but doesn't make a difference?

The latest source that I downloaded was from http://bitbucket.org/bos/hgbook which is the repository for the Mercurial book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem.  The `Content-Type` header in the download is wonky:

```
% GET -Ssed http://host/mayorguard/archive/tip.tar.bz2
GET http://ry4an.org/hg/mayorguard/archive/tip.tar.bz2 --> 200 Script output follows
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 19:01:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: application/x-tar
Client-Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 19:01:00 GMT
Client-Peer: 75.146.191.221:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mayorguard-dee99508cd77.tar.bz2
```

Notice the `Content-Disposition` header suggests the browser use a filename with the correct extension, but the `Content-Type` header says it's a `.tar` file.  When I do that download in Google Chrome I get a resulting file named mayorguard-hashid.tar.gz.tar which isn't right.

The example above was from hgweb and the one below is from bitbucket:

```
% GET -Ssed http://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/etsy-php/get/000000000000.bz2
GET http://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/etsy-php/get/000000000000.bz2 --> 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=1800
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 19:05:16 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Content-Length: 189
Content-Type: application/x-tar
Expires: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 19:35:16 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 19:05:16 GMT
Client-Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 19:05:16 GMT
Client-Peer: 207.223.240.182:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=etsy-php-000000000000.bz2
```

I'd say that Mercurial is giving bad info and the browser is overthinking the filename.

Comment: That seems to make sense, but I'm no expert on HTTP.  Is there a way to report this back to the Mercurial development team?

Comment: I sent a patch correcting the content types to their development list this afternoon.  We'll see where it goes.

Comment: Patch was accepted into mercurial today.  It'll be in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in bitbucket, please report it to them: http://bitbucket.org/jespern/bitbucket/issues/new/

Comment: But the same thing happens with "hg serve", wouldn't that point to a more likely problem in Mercurial?  I'm just speculating out loud.

Comment: I am using 1.6.3.  When you hover over the links they appear normal, but when you actually download the file you get something else.  I just did an "hg serve" on my local clone of the hgbook repository, and the file that I got was named hgbook-93154fbaae9b.tar.bz2.tar which is a little better than BitBucket, but still strange.

Comment: I've got the why of that in my answer.  It's extension and Content-Type not matching so your browser "helps" by affixing the "right" extension for the Content-Type it's being told.